# Putting multiple mySQL queries into one complicated one

Tags: mysql

Im finding it very hard to learn how to build more complicated queries in mySQL.

Hopefully, through this question, I can gain some more insight as to how to develop multi-level queries inside a single query.

I have a tagging system.

```
tbl1: ktbridge
ktbridge_id
threads_id
keywords_id

tbl2: threads
threads_id
subject
etc

tbl3: keywords
keywords_id
keyword
related_id
```

Above is my current set up.

For data, I have:

```
INSERT INTO `ktbridge` (`ktbridge_id`, `threads_id`, `keywords_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 9);

INSERT INTO `keywords` (`keyword_id`, `keyword`, `related_id`) VALUES
(5, 'Sports', 0),
(6, 'Baseball', 5),
(7, 'football', 5),
(8, 'Curling', 5),
(9, 'Pitchers', 6),
(10, 'Catchers', 6),

INSERT INTO `threads` (`threads_id`, `subject`, `body`, `users_id`, `timestamp`, `replystamp`) VALUES
(1, 'Sports - Baseball - Pitchers - Subject', 'Sports - Baseball - Pitchers - Body', 1, '2013-01-09 14:09:40', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

The goal here, is to return the threads that are related to the keyword_id that is provided.

The tough part is that if "baseball" is selected, it returns baseball threads.  However, if "sports" is selected, it returns all threads below it, based on the "related_id" in the `keywords` table.  So it would return all threads based on baseball, football, and curling.

Is this a possibility? Or will it require multiple queries? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, I favour clarity over efficiency, and let the optimiser deal with it as it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does require multiple queries, but you can nest them and select from within the inner select. I think the following should work (or at least get you started). Note that this is MySQL, but should be portable to other RDBM systems:

```
SELECT * FROM `threads` WHERE `threads`.`threads_id` IN (
  SELECT `threads_id` FROM `ktbridge` WHERE `ktbridge`.`keywords_id` IN (
    SELECT `keywords_id` FROM `keywords` 
      WHERE `keywords`.`id` = 5 OR `keywords`.`related_id` = 5
    )
  );
```

[MySQL doc reference for "IN"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//any-in-some-subqueries.html)

Comment: Well done. thank you.  This is exactly what I asked (and much simpler than the way I threw together).  Now to experiment with a dynamic way to go further than 1 related piece down...

Comment: Good luck... and btw, my recommendation is to become very familiar with your DB tool of choice (command line, phpmyadmin, whatevs) and just try different queries, but also be sure to try the same query with different input so that you know it's not a fluke of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  One more thing if you don't mind: Using the ktbridge table..should I just include more rows to store more relations? Or would there be any benefit in creating a much more complicated php/dynamically created query?

Comment: The real question is can a thread have more than one keyword? If so, then you need the ktbridge to map each thread to each of it's keywords in addition to the "related" mapping on the keywords table itself. If not, you can kill that table and put the keyword id on the threads table. Of course, have you considered if a keyword can have multiple relations? :) Right now, it you only have a two-tiered, no cross-over organization. What about an "Indoor" keyword, in which case curling is valid, but not baseball. Sorry if I'm causing you more work!

Comment: Thanks. very interesting...I completely overlooked the idea that i no longer needed the ktbridge on the way I was implementing it based on the information above.  However, I think im just going to go the route where each thread has multiple tags and keep it the way it is now.  More DB entries..but who cares?